# getting multiple values from one table and using to retrive data from other table in stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to retrieve data from one table and use it to retrieve data from other table using stored procedure.

```
cart table
    CartId,
    PrdouctId -> should retrieve data from productinfo table 
    EmailId ->should Retrieve data from cart table that who many cart are register in this EmailId 
    cost,
    Quantity ,
    Ram -> contains HardWareId
    GraphicCard ->contains HardWareId
    ScreenSize ->contains HardWareId

ProductInfo Table
    ProductId,
    BrandlName,
    ModelName,
    Processor,

HardwareInfo table
    HardWareId,
    HardwareName,
    HarwareCost,
```

`@EmailId` will be supplied to the stored procedure

```
Select @ProductId =[productId],@Ram = [Ram] from cart where EmailId = @EmailId 
Select [BrandName],[ModelName] from ProductInfo where ProductId = @productId
select [HardwareName],[HardwareCost] from HardwareInfo where HardwareId = @Ram
```

`BrandName`, `ModelName`, `Processor`,`Ram`,`GraphicCard`,`ScreeSize` will be shown to user in list view.

Is correct the way that I'm trying to do it?

Comment: I think the best way to approach this would be to write some code.

Comment: i need to show this retrieved data in listview

Comment: There is really not enough information here to help you.   Add some sample table structures, and what kind of output you'd like to see, and what you've tried so far, and you'll likely get a response

Comment: You should already have two queries: one that can "retrieve data from one table", and a second that would "retrieve data from other table" for a single value.  If you can show us these two queries, we can show you how to put them together so that the second query uses the results of the first query.

Comment: is this data sufficient please help me out

Comment: @CHANDRAHAS: read our comments and reply to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this.

```
create procedure GetCartByEmailId
  @EmailId int
as  

select P.BrandName,
       P.ModelName,
       HR.HardwareName as RamName,
       HR.HardwareCost as RamCost,
       HG.HardwareName as GraphicCard,
       HG.HardwareCost as GraphicCardCost,
       HS.HardwareName as ScreenSize
from Cart as C
  inner join ProductInfo as P
    on C.ProductId = P.ProductId
  left outer join HardwareInfo as HR
    on C.Ram = HR.HardwareID
  left outer join HardwareInfo as HG
    on C.GraphicCard = HG.HardwareID
  left outer join HardwareInfo as HS
    on C.ScreenSize = HS.HardwareID
where C.EmailId = @EmailId
```

Comment: c.GraphicCard ,c.ScreenSize then i must write it c.Ram = H.HardwareId,c.GraphicCard = H.HardwareID,c.ScreenSize = H.HardwareID

Comment: @CHANDRAHAS - I have no idea. Those columns is not specified in your question.

Comment: Mikael Eriksson:@Mikael Eriksson yes i know please i will modify the question can look it once more it will be great help